# How to pivot two values in mysql?

Tags: mysql, pivot

i've the following table structure:

```
+-------+----------+------+------------+------------+
| agent | product  | type | value_2013 | value_2014 |
+-------+----------+------+------------+------------+
| John  | product1 | A    |         10 |         11 |
| John  | product1 | C    |         14 |         13 |
| Mike  | product1 | A    |         11 |         20 |
| Mike  | product2 | C    |         13 |         15 |
+-------+----------+------+------------+------------+
```

type is always A or C
I need to transform (pivot) in a table like this

```
 agent, product, type, value_2013_A, value_2013_C, value_2014_A, value_2014_C

 ...
 ...
```

I've write the following SQL query but it not works. It take ONLY first type

```
SELECT agent,product,
 case when type='C' then value_2013 else 0 end as value_2013_C,   <-- take this value,ok!
 case when type='C' then value_2013 else 0 end as value_2013_A,    <-- but obviously not take this value
 case when type='A' then impap else 0 end as value_2014_A,        <-- take this value, ok!
 case when type='A' then impac else 0 end as value_2014_C          <-- but obviously not take this value
    FROM  mytable 
    GROUP BY agent,product;
```

How to modify it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to make max. try that

```
 SELECT agent,product,
 max(case when type='C' then value_2013 else 0 end) as value_2013_C,   
 max(case when type='C' then value_2013 else 0 end) as value_2013_A,    
 max(case when type='A' then impap else 0 end) as value_2014_A,        
 max(case when type='A' then impac else 0 end ) as value_2014_C         
 FROM  mytable 
 GROUP BY agent,product;
```

Comment: I can't understand how it works (why using max??).. but it works! thanks a lot !

Comment: you welcome :). with max is to get just one value per specified column, otherwise you will get multiple values.